# AWK - Sum a column passed as parameter from a bash script

Tags: variables, awk, parameters, sum

i ve written a bash script that eventually calls on this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "Calculate sum of column: "} { sum += 5; print $0 } { print "Sum of column:", sum, "\n"}'
```

I would like to edit that a little bit, so the column to be summed is passed as a parameter from the bash wrapper script. I have tried:

```
awk -v var="$column" 'BEGIN { print "Calculate sum of column: "} { sum += var; print $0 } { print "Sum of column:", sum, "\n"}'
```

but it basicly adds the same number x NR, which is expected. What i dont know is how to make :

```
sum += var
```

translate to

```
sum += $var.
```

so that it catches the column number.

So far i ve tried:

```
awk -v var="$column" 'BEGIN { PRINT "Sum:" } { sum += $var; } END { print sum } FILE_IN > FILE_OT
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Did you try `sum+=$var` and is not working?

Comment: Yes, i m adding the exact line i m trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not reproducable, sorry. If column is assigned should work ok:

```
$ column=5;echo "a b c d 15 f" |awk -v var="$column" 'BEGIN { print "Sum:" } { sum += $var; } END { print sum }'
Sum:
15
```

PS: Dont write print in capital letters.

With file;

```
$ cat file11
a b c d 15 f
$ column=5;awk -v var="$column" 'BEGIN { print "Sum:" } { sum += $var; } END { print sum }' file11
Sum:
15
```

Comment: It worked your way with cat FILE_IN | awk ..., thanks for your reply Γιωργο!

Comment: cat should not be the reason

Comment: @onlyf see test with file. You dont need cat with awk